# Is the graph of $f(x) = (x^2-4)/(x-2)$ the same as $f(x) = (x+2)$?

Tags: limits, functions

this might be a dumb question, but I was wondering what is the difference of graphs between $f(x) = (x^2-4)/(x-2)$  and $f(x) = (x+2)$. I understand if we simply the $f(x) = (x^2-4)/(x-2)$ it will come down to $f(x) = (x+2)$. But without simplifying it, they both behave differently at x = 2 and how would that impact their graph. I searched online, and all they would draw would be the same graph for both of them, but it doesn't feel right.

Comment: The first $f(x)$ isn't defined over all of $\mathbb R$. That's the difference. When graphing, the graphs would be the same, except there would be a gap at $x=2$ for the first function.

Comment: @DonThousand thanks...it cleared most of my confusion..however I still have one more ... if I can put it in different terms .. if we can ignore the graphs ... mathematically at least from what I understand [ (x^-4)/x-2 = x+2 ] .. if their graph is not the same .. that means [ (x^-4)/x-2 = x+2 ] doesn't hold true and my understanding is wrong about it ?

Comment: It's all about domains. On the domain $\mathbb R\setminus\{2\}$, the functions are equal. On the domain $\mathbb R$, they are not, since one is not defined everywhere on the domain.

Answer (score 4):

the graph of $f(x) = \frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$ is not defined at $x = 2$, it looks exactly like the graph of $x + 2$, but it has a hole at $f(2)$, graphic calculators usually don't graph that hole. Notice that $lim_{x\to\ 2} f(x)$ does exist, though $f(2)$ is not defined. when something like that happens, it is called a removable discontinuity, because we can define a new function $g(x) = f(x)$ if $ x \neq 2$ and $g(x) = 4$ if $x = 2$, this new function is continuous at 2.

Comment: Good answer, but a minor nitpick. You write, "though it's not equal to $f(2)$". That somehow implies that $f$ is defined at $2$, which it is not.

Comment: @Donlans Donlans thanks...it cleared most of my confusion..however I still have one more ... if I can put it in different terms .. if we can ignore the graphs ... mathematically at least from what I understand [ (x^-4)/x-2 = x+2 ] .. if their graph is not the same .. that means [ (x^-4)/x-2 = x+2 ] doesn't hold true and my understanding is wrong about it ?

Comment: @ Don Thousand  thanks, I edited now

Comment: @waliflower $\frac{x^2 - 4}{x-2} = x+2$ is correct, but you need to restrict the domain of the function. if your original function is $f(x) = \frac{x^2 - 4}{x-2}$ which simplifies to $x + 2$. you can't evaluate at $x = 2$ because it's not defined.

Comment: @DonlansDonlans hmm..you mean the relation [ (x^-4)/x-2 = x+2 ] holds true for all the values in R except at x = 2 ...if I can take another example .. let's say relation [x/x = 1] will always hold true as long as x != 0 ...that means each time nominator and denominator in Algebraic fraction cancels out, there is always an exception that it won't cancel out on a specific number ...? interesting

Comment: @waliflower consider the functions $f(x) = \frac{x}{x}$ and $g(x) = 1$, we have that $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \neq 0$, because $f(0)$ is not defined, in other words, $f(0)$ makes no sense. when the numerator and denominator cancel out, the domain stays the same, for the function $f(x) = \frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$, its domain is the set of all reals except $2$. and if you simplify, the domain stays the same. now consider the function $g(x) = \frac{(x+2)(x^2 + 2)}{x^2 + 2}$ which simplifies to $x+2$, in this case, you can evaluate it at all values because the domain are all the real.

Comment: @DonlansDonlans thanks for removing my confusion .. it is clear now..

Answer (score 3):

They are not the same graph since they differ at one point.

The graph of $f(x)=\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$ has a very small hole at $x=2$, see my picture:

[image]

Comment: Why do so many people prefer words over graphs?

Comment: I guess this is using Desmos. I am not sure why Desmos put the whole by default!

Answer (score 0):

They are the same except for the removable discontinuity.

Comment: Well... then they're not the same.

Comment: That's what "except" means, right? Should I have added more to my answer?

Comment: Instead of saying except just say that they're not the same because of the discontinuity.

Comment: But I'd like to stress that, essentially, everything else about the two functions are the same.

Comment: That's a very non-rigorous way of looking at it. Although it's a nitpick, it's important. Sure, they "look" the same, but by that standard, the graph of $y=x^{2}$ "looks" like the graph of $y=x^{20}$ and is pretty much the same function.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think this answer works on a beginner level (which is the lebel of the question, and although N. Bar has a valid point, $x^{20}$ does not at all look like $x^2$ in the same colloquial way that the two graphs in the question look like each other, at least in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Before graphing a function, as a general rule, you have to pose the C.E. (or existence condition). For the fraction $x\neq 2$ while for the second $\forall x \in R$. The graph aren't the same in fact in $y=\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$ the point $x=2$ isn't possible. In $y=x+2$ there is this point.